# Windows Service not writing to EventLog on autostart

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, windows-services, event-log

I’m having this problem... when I manually start/stop the windows service it works as expected an I get the log entry. However, if I turn off and restart the machine the service status is running but it has not logged the stop message while the computer was shutdown nor it has logged the start message when it was turned on. The OS is Windows 10.

I’m running mad on this issue. The code is the most basic windows service written in C# writing to the log on the OnStart and OnClose methods. Nothing more.

I’ve also tried writing on the filesystem with the same results. When manualy started/stopped it is successful; but on automatic start or on system shutdown it fails.

I’ve runned out of ideas.

This is the code I'm running:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    private bool _loggedLogPath = false;

    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.AutoLog = true;
        this.CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
        this.CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
        this.CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        this.CanShutdown = true;
        this.CanStop = true;
        this.CanStop = true;
    }

    private void LogToFile(string message)
    {
        try
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData), "TestService.txt");

            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(path, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine(String.Concat(DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"), ": ", message));
                writer.Flush();
            }

            if (!this._loggedLogPath)
            {
                this.EventLog.WriteEntry(String.Concat("The log path is: ", path));
                this._loggedLogPath = true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            // Ignore exceptions to avoid crashing the service.
        }

    }

    protected override void OnContinue()
    {
        this.EventLog.WriteEntry("OnContinue method Called.");
        LogToFile("OnContinue method called.");
        base.OnContinue();
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        this.EventLog.WriteEntry("OnPause method called");
        LogToFile("OnPause method called.");
        base.OnPause();
    }

    protected override bool OnPowerEvent(PowerBroadcastStatus powerStatus)
    {
        this.EventLog.WriteEntry("OnPowerEvent method called");
        LogToFile(String.Format("OnPowerEvent method called ({0}).", powerStatus.ToString()));
        return base.OnPowerEvent(powerStatus);
    }

    protected override void OnSessionChange(SessionChangeDescription changeDescription)
    {
        this.EventLog.WriteEntry(String.Format("OnSessionChange method called ({0}).", changeDescription.Reason.ToString()));
        LogToFile(String.Format("OnSessionChange method called ({0}).", changeDescription.Reason.ToString()));
        base.OnSessionChange(changeDescription);
    }

    protected override void OnShutdown()
    {
        this.EventLog.WriteEntry("OnShutdown method called.");
        LogToFile("OnShutdown method called.");
        base.OnShutdown();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        this.EventLog.WriteEntry("OnStart method called.");
        LogToFile("OnStart method called.");
        base.OnStart(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        this.EventLog.WriteEntry("OnStop method called.");
        LogToFile("OnStop method called.");
        base.OnStop();
    }
}
```

The logged messages to filesystem are:

> 2020-02-05 11:17:10: OnSessionChange method called (RemoteConnect).
>
> 2020-02-05 11:17:13: OnSessionChange method called (SessionLogoff).
>
> 2020-02-05 11:17:14: OnSessionChange method called (ConsoleDisconnect).
>
> 2020-02-05 11:17:14: OnSessionChange method called (RemoteDisconnect).
>
> 2020-02-05 11:17:15: OnSessionChange method called (ConsoleConnect).
>
> 2020-02-05 11:17:15: OnPowerEvent method called (Suspend).
>
> 2020-02-05 11:17:50: OnPowerEvent method called (ResumeSuspend).
>
> 2020-02-05 11:17:50: OnPowerEvent method called (ResumeAutomatic).
>
> 2020-02-05 11:18:12: OnSessionChange method called (SessionLogon).

Answer (score 0):

You can override following events provided by windows service and check if it is logging to file system.

OnShutdown() , OnPowerEvent()

Ex:

```
        /// <summary>
        /// Will be called when system goes to shutdown mode. 
        /// </summary>
        protected override void OnShutdown()
        {
           //Log  
            base.OnShutdown();
        }
```

Also make sure to set properties related to these inside service constructor .

```
        CanPauseAndContinue = true;
        CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;
        CanHandlePowerEvent = true;
        CanShutdown = true;
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, thanks for the response. I've added some source code. OnShutdown won't log. OnPowerEvent or OnSessionChange do log. But still have no control over the OnStart method to keep logs or warn if something went wrong. Nor will i be able to access some files to get the job done :/

Comment: How are you logging to file system ?